# Is it a good etiquette to mark your answer on a poll question community-wiki, even if the question isn't?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki, etiquette

Like this question: 
[Which ‘super shell scripting’ language should I learn, perl, ruby or tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832811/which-super-shell-scripting-language-should-i-learn-perl-ruby-or-tcl)
The question is closed now, but it had several answers before it's been closed.

The top answer is merely a personal preference that just says:

> I'm a big fan of perl so that's what I
>   would recommend.

The question isn't community-wiki, and it's clearly a poll question that has to be.

Do you consider it a good etiquette to post answers on these questions as community wiki? I think you should be nice and not demand some reputation points because you're telling your personal preference that lots like and would upvote it.

*I'm not taking particularly about the user who posted that answer, just an example.*

Comment: and yet you didn't make *THIS* cw...

Comment: My mistake, edited it :) Thanks warren.

Comment: On Meta, the CW rules are a little ... different. Primarily because just about everything is a discussion. And the answer, as Shog9 has graciously pointed out, is **yes.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes**.

Comment: Thanks for a simple answer :) +1

Comment: 15 people agree that it's a good etiquette. Great.

Answer (score 3):

There's two results of marking your answer as community wiki:

- You don't get reputation points.
- Many more people can edit your post.

When I state my firmly-held opinions, I might have a bigger problem with the second bullet point than the first.

Comment: Seconded.  If your opinion is bearing your name, let it be your words.

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed some people mark their answer as CW when they're about to say something controversial and don't want to lose rep when it's down-voted... or gain rep when it's up-voted.

Comment: Bad move for rep.  Controversial opinions are great for rep, because the upvotes help you about five times more than the downvotes hurt you, and if you get below zero you're likely to get sympathy upvotes.  (Not that I would ever advocate gaming for rep, but I wouldn't use CW just to safeguard myself from rep loss.)

Comment: Yep, I know this phenomena.

Comment: Just this day one my answer got downvoted to -4 or -5, but somehow made it back up to 0. Certainly brought some funds. :)